# Unable to find Birch Module in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to the Birch algorithm within the sklearn clustering package.

```
from sklearn import cluster
birch = cluster.Birch(n_clusters=2)
```

Results in:

> 'module' object has no attribute 'Birch'

I am able to use other algorithms such as k-means from the clustering package but the Birch gives the error identified above.

Using scikit-learn version: 0.15.2

Comment: It should be equivalent but have you tried "from sklearn.cluster import Birch" then "birch = Birch(n_clusters=2)"?

Comment: Tried your suggestion but results in: cannot import name Birch

Comment: What version sklearn do you have installed I think this is a new feature, for instance it's not in `0.15.2` but is in `0.16.0`

Comment: Just say this comment while making the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade your sklearn, Birch is not available in version `0.15.2` try upgrading to `0.16.0` which is the current stable version.

This is verified on the sklearn website: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/whats_new.html#highlights

> cluster.Birch clustering method for large-scale datasets.

This was added to version `0.16.0`

Comment: I had to upgrade the installation using: `pip install -U scikit-learn`